# Give access to some node module for all users OSX

Tags: macos, node.js, unix, npm

I've installed coffee-script node module. Only my user can execute "coffee" command. I want to give it to other users in OS. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `sudo npm install --global coffee-script`?

Comment: I install it in that way.

Comment: what is the output of running `which coffee` under both users